# In Javascript, how to build a function which returns a value after getting data from a API call?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have created a function which queries the Google Analytic API and get some data. It works fine. I used a console.log to confirm. But I need to get this data to a variable. Here's the function :

```
function getActiveUsers() {
    ...
    // Set data

      authClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
          if (err) {
              console.log(err);
              return;
          }

          analytics.data.realtime.get({
              auth: authClient,
              'ids': 'ga:ID',
              'metrics': 'rt:activeUsers'
          }, function(err, result) {
              console.log(err);
              return result; // I want this result
          });

      });
}
```

Now I wont the result into a variable like this :

```
result = getActiveUsers();
```

How can I do this? Please help.

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-do-i-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call) should help.

Comment: You can use something like that 

`function getActiveUsers() {
      return new Promise(function (resolve, reject) {
        authClient.authorize(function(err, tokens) {
              if (err) {
                  reject(err);
                  return;
              }
    
              analytics.data.realtime.get({...}, function(err, result) {
                  if (err) {
                    reject(err);
                  }
                  resolve(resolt);
              });
          });
      });
    }`

Comment: Then:

`var promise = getActiveUsers();
    promise
      .then(function(result) {
        // we can use result here
      })
      .catch(function(err) {
        // handle error here
      });`

Comment: Reopen question please, then I will pastie it in response